# pgfplotstable: parsing string data when "S" is present

Tags: pgfplotstable

the following table works:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/0/.style={
        column name=z,
        string type},
    columns/1/.style={
        column name=x,
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.1]},
    },
    columns/2/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=3.0]},
    },
    columns/3/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.0]},
    },
    columns/4/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.0]},
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
   ]{
2017-09-26    9.2    144 80  62
2017-09-27   10.2    144 80  62
   }
\end{document}
```

but if i after first column add one more column with time (see *mwe* below), i receive error:

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 2017-09-27 as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ?-09-27'..
```

this not works:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/0/.style={
        column name=z,
        string type},
    columns/1/.style={
        column name=z,
        string type},
    columns/2/.style={
        column name=x,
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.1]},
    },
    columns/3/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=3.0]},
    },
    columns/4/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.0]},
    },
    columns/5/.style={
        column name={y},
        string type,
        column type={S[table-format=2.0]},
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
   ]{
2017-09-26   9:00    9.2    144 80  62
2017-09-27  11:30   10.2    144 80  62
   }
\end{document}
```

why now the first column is not parsing as in the first example?

Comment: did you try using `display columns` instead for nameless column referral?

Comment: @percusse, no i didn't. i'm quit beginner in `pgfplotstable`, so i'm not aware to this possibilities.but it doesn't work. I try the following: `display columns/1/.style={column name=z,string type},` (adequately  for all columns).

Comment: @percusse, your suggestion works! in the first test i made spelling error (`diplay columns` instead of `display columns`). if you will "transform" your comment to answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @percusse, unfortunately with `display columns` arise new problem: first row of data is not shown. i temporary solve this, that i add for the first row `x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5`. interesting, if i add just `0 1 2 3 4 5` than this row is displayed.  i read documentation again and if i will not figured out, what is going on, i will ask new question.

Comment: you need to add `header=false`. It's assuming that the first row is the column names

Comment: I don't have access to TeX but only phone so please feel free to add an answer as you wish.

Comment: i can wait on you. meanwhile i will reading package documentation  (again).